# MyISAM utf-8 encoding issues

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, myisam

I converted a database from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8_unicode_ci collation after havind some trouble storing special characters.
I've set the character set of the database, tables and columns to utf8 and the collation to utf8_unicode_ci.

Only the InnoDB tables store the utf-8 data correctly, and the MyISAM tables don't. ü becomes Ã¼ for example.

What could be going on here? Am I missing something?

MySQL version 5.0.77

Comment: What does "SHOW CREATE TABLE the_myisam_table" shows ?

Comment: Every possible column is utf8_unicode_ci, the table's default charset is utf8 and the collation utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Is the connection using the UTF8 charset ? If not this is the problem. If yes, then the conversion gone bad and the data in the table has been converted from latin1 to utf8 twice.

Comment: Yes it is. I also tried exporting the database and deleting it. Then import all the data again. That should work right? But the problem remains the same.

Comment: Is the data that was already stored in the database mangled or is data that you're newly inputting into it mangled? Please post how exactly you connect the database (code please).

Comment: Was the answer to this ever discovered?

Comment: I did an export and manually search & replaced all faulty characters if I remember correctly. Also make sure the database connection is UTF-8. I Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you are using a framework (let's say Rails) you must ensure that the connection to the database is using the proper encoding.  In Rails it would be defined as an argument in your database.yml file with `encoding: utf8`

Answer (score 0):

use on new table InnoDB

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(my_column USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8);
```